# How to add new lines of XML based on PHP variables?

Tags: php, xml

I'm very much new to XML and would appreciate any guidance or help on this issue I've been trying to tackle for hours.

**Objective**

I have a simple form which has some check boxes. If the checkbox is checked, I would like it to add some code to the XML. This is all in 1 file here and is a sample file I received in working on a third party API.

The first part of the code is finding whether a checkbox is checked. Then I define a variable based on the value of the POST option.

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$signature = $_POST['signature'];

if($signature == "SO") {
    $sig_option = htmlentities("<option-code>SO</option>");
}
else {
    $sig_option = "";
} } ?>
```

The next part is the XML generation where I would like it to be inputted if the checkbox value is = "SO". Where the `{$sig_option}` variable is, I would like it to put in the `<option-code>SO</option-code>`

```
    $xmlRequest = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
............................
<options>
    <option>
        <option-code>COV</option-code>
        <option-amount>{$covAmount}</option-amount>    
    {$sig_option}
    </option>
</options> 
.............
```

I'm not sure if there's a way that I can do this based on a POST form submission in PHP, but if someone can help out, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: don't use html entitles on your entire new node. You'd be trying to insert `&lt;option-code .... &gt;` into your html document, which will be a syntax error.  use html entities on the CONTENTS of your nodes, e.g. `htmlentities('SO')`, but the xml tags themselves cannot be encoded.

Comment: Thanks @MarcB . Would you happen to know a way that I can get it to encode properly into the XML area of the code?

Comment: exactly what you're doing now should be fine, just make sure you're inserting valid xml, because yours isn't. Your open/close tags are mismatched: `<option-code>` v.s. `</option>`.

Comment: Thanks again Marc. My code above was just a typo from my actual script. The API is spitting an error at me still saying "option with anonymous type may not have text content". I'm not sure what this means, but if I hard code it in <option-code>SO</option-code>, it works fine. When I try to put in the var {$sig_option}, it spits that error at me. @MarcB